# (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: surfers.id

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am getting

```
"(sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: surfers.id
[SQL: INSERT INTO surfers (name, hometown, wipeouts, rank) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Bruno', 'Chicago', 20, 10)]"
```

error when trying to commit some tables in sqlalchemy. I am having trouble figuring out exactly why. I tried enabling iteration as well when creating the classes themselves but that did not work either. Can somebody please help me figure out how to resolve this? Details below:

```
# Import SQL Alchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Import and establish Base for which classes will be 
constructed 
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

# Import modules to declare columns and column data types
from sqlalchemy import Table, ForeignKey, Column, Integer, String, Float

# Create Surfer and Board classes
# ----------------------------------

class Surfer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'surfers'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    surfer_id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    hometown = Column(String(255))
    wipeouts = Column(Integer)
    rank = Column(Integer)

class Board(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'surfboards'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    surfer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('surfers.surfer_id'))
    board_name = Column(String(255))
    color = Column(String(255))
    length = Column(Integer)

# Create specific instances of the Surfer and Board classes
# ----------------------------------
# Create a new surfer named "Bruno"
# Create a new board and associate it with a surfer's ID

Bruno = Surfer(name = 'Bruno', hometown = 'Chicago', wipeouts = 20, rank = 10)

new_board = Board(surfer_id = Bruno.surfer_id, board_name = 'yuh', color = 'purple', length =8)

# Create Database Connection
# ----------------------------------
# Establish Connection to a sqlite database

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///surfer.sqlite")
conn = engine.connect()
Base.metadata.create_all(conn)
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
session = Session(bind=engine)

# To push the objects made and query the server we use a Session 
object
session.add(Bruno)
session.add(new_board)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Hmm, it’s good that it’s running properly, but I wonder why it won’t do the same on my machine.

Comment: Why do you have `__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}`?

Comment: I was under the assumption that enabling extend would allow me to overwrite the tables without having to restart the kernel in jupyter notebook. Please correct me if I am wrong.